# Jquery image fade with sequential sources

Tags: jquery, settimeout, fade

I made a rough script to change an image with fadein fade out, I want to change it every 5 seconds while taking the new one from a pool of images.
In this case I have 4 jpegs with sequential names: `dish1 dish2 dish3 dish4` but it results in a pageload and no changes on the image:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  function chngImg(curImg=1,imgNum=4){
    var src = "immagini/dishes_pizze/dish" + curImg + ".jpg";
    $('#picture').fadeOut("slow");
    $('#picture').attr('src', src);
    $('#picture').fadeIn("slow");
    curImg++;
    if (curImg>imgNum){
      curImg=1;
    } //end if
    setTimeout('chngImg(curImg, imgNum);', 5000);
  } // end chngimg
}); //endready
```

Any help would be useful, I'm new with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you pass function name in `setTimeout` function, the function must be public but in your code, the function `chngImg` is declared inside `$(document).ready`. It's local function, that's why your code doesnt run. And you cant set default value of arguments.

Your code should be

```
function chngImg(curImg, imgNum) {
    if (!curImg) {
        curImg = 1;
    }

    if (!imgNum) {
        imgNum = 4;
    }

    var src = "immagini/dishes_pizze/dish" + curImg + ".jpg";
    $('#picture').fadeOut("slow");
    $('#picture').attr('src', src);
    $('#picture').fadeIn("slow");
    curImg++;
    if (curImg > imgNum) {
        curImg = 1;
    } //end if
    setTimeout('chngImg(curImg, imgNum);', 5000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    chngImg();
});
```

Or you can pass callback to `setTimeout` like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function chngImg(curImg, imgNum) {
        if (!curImg) {
            curImg = 1;
        }

        if (!imgNum) {
            imgNum = 4;
        }

        var src = "immagini/dishes_pizze/dish" + curImg + ".jpg";
        $('#picture').fadeOut("slow");
        $('#picture').attr('src', src);
        $('#picture').fadeIn("slow");
        curImg++;
        if (curImg > imgNum) {
            curImg = 1;
        } //end if

        setTimeout(function() {
            chngImg(curImg, imgNum);
        }, 5000);
    }

    chngImg();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried both the codes and the second one works pretty fine but there is still a problem, the image changes before the fadeout is complete so you actually see the image which changes and you should not.

I edited the changing image code in this as shown by @arun:

    $('#picture').fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $(this).attr('src', src).fadeIn("slow")});

that way it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() { chngImg(curImg, imgNum) }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your script, try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var curImg = 1,
        imgNum = 4;

    //method signature does not allow default values
    function chngImg() {
        var src = "immagini/dishes_pizze/dish" + curImg + ".jpg";
        //change source after the image is hidden
        $('#picture').fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).attr('src', src).fadeIn("slow", function () {
                //again schdule next iteration using setTimeout()
                setTimeout(chngImg, 5000)
            });
        });
        curImg++;
        if (curImg > imgNum) {
            curImg = 1;
        } //end if 
    } // end chngimg 
    //initialize the loop
    chngImg();
}); //endready
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A84PS/)

A better way is to use [`setInterval(func, delay)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval), that will call your function every `delay` miliseconds.
In the `curImg` variable we store the actual number of the image globally, then we call the `chngImg()` function with `setInterval()` that will execute it every 5 seconds. The `chngImg()` function is identical with yours.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var curImg = 1;
    setInterval(function chngImg(imgNum) {
        var src = "immagini/dishes_pizze/dish" + curImg + ".jpg";
        $('#picture').fadeOut("slow");
        $('#picture').attr('src', src);
        $('#picture').fadeIn("slow");
        ++curImg;
        if (curImg > imgNum) {
            curImg = 1;
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```